# Calculating the Recurrence Relation T(n)=T(n / log n) + Θ(1)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, complexity-theory, recurrence

The question comes from [Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) 3rd Edition, P63, Problem 3-6, where it's introduced as ***Iterated functions***. I rewrite it as follows:

```
int T(int n){
   for(int count = 0; n > 2 ; ++count)
   {
      n = n/log₂(n); 
   }
   return count;
}
```

Then give as tight a bound as possible on `T(n)`.

I can make it `O(log n)` and `Ω(log n / log log n)`, but can it be tighter?

---

PS: Using Mathematica, I've learned that when `n=1*10^3281039`, `T(n)=500000`

and the same time, `T(n)=1.072435*log n/ log log n`

and the coefficient declines with `n` from `1.22943` (`n = 2.07126*10^235`) to `1.072435` (`n = 1*10^3281039`).

May this information be helpful.

Comment: You did try plugging in one of those bounds and seeing if they satisfy the recurrence (possibly with simple modifications), right?

Comment: I tried the Ω for I consider it more likely. And so it seems to be, because (log log N=23.3777) can make a significant difference, while the coefficient changes little. @Hurkyl

Comment: That interesting question belongs to Computer Science. I flagged it as such.

Comment: @Elyasin: I feel like it's more of a calculus problem than a computer science problem, since the guts of the problem are doing error analysis on estimates of functions.

Comment: You might be right. I think it's not a programming problem. I knew only of CS till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the lower bound is pretty good, so I tried to proof that the upper bound is `O(log n / log log n)`. 
But let me first explain the other bounds (just for a better understanding).

#### TL;DR

`T(n)` is in `Θ(log n / log log n)`.

#### T(n) is in `O(log n)`

This can be seen by modifying `n := n/log₂n` to `n := n/2`.
It needs `O(log₂ n)` steps until `n ≤ 2` holds.

#### T(n) is in `Ω(log n / log log n)`

This can be seen by modifying `n := n/log₂(n)` to `n := n/m`, where `m` is the initial value of `log n`.
Solving the equation
`n / (log n)x < 2` for `x` leads us to

```
               log n - x log log n < log 2
    ⇔                log n - log 2 < x log log n
    ⇔  (log n - log 2) / log log n < x

    ⇒ x ∈ Ω(log n / log log n)
```

#### Improving the upper bound: `O(log n) → O(log n / log log n)`

Now let us try to improve the upper bound. Instead of dividing `n` by a fixed constant (namely `2` in the above proof) we divide `n` as long by the initial value of `log(n)/2` as the current value of `log(n)` is bigger. To be more clearer have a look at the modified code:

```
int T₂(int n){
     n_old = n;
     for(int count=0; n>2 ;++count)
     {
         n = n / (log₂(n_old)/2);

         if(log₂(n)) <= log₂(n_old)/2)
         {
            n_old = n;
         }
     }
     return count;
}
```

The complexity of the function `T₂` is clearly an upper bound for the function `T`, since `log₂(n_old)/2 < log₂(n)` holds for the whole time.

Now we need to know how many times we divide by each `1/2⋅log(n_old)`:

```
    n / (log(sqrt(n)))x ≤ sqrt(n)
⇔           n / sqrt(n) ≤ log(sqrt(n))x
⇔          log(sqrt(n)) ≤ x log(log(sqrt(n)))

⇔    log(sqrt(n)) / log(log(sqrt(n)))  ≤ x
```

So we get the recurrence formula `T₂(n) = T(sqrt(n)) + O(log(sqrt(n)) / log(log(sqrt(n))))`.

Now we need to know how often this formula has to be expanded until `n < 2` holds.

```
        n2-x < 2
⇔       2-x⋅log n < log 2
⇔       -x log 2 + log log n < log 2
⇔       log log n < log 2 + x log 2
⇔       log log n < (x + 1) log 2
```

So we need to expand the formula about `log log n` times.

Now it gets a little bit harder. (Have also a look at the [Mike_Dog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30857921/3440545))

```
T₂(n) = T(sqrt(n)) + log(sqrt(n)) / log(log(sqrt(n)))
      = Σk=1,...,log log n - 1 2-k⋅log(n) / log(2-k⋅log n))
      = log(n) ⋅ Σk=1,...,log log n - 1 2-k / (-k + log log n))
(1)   = log(n) ⋅ Σk=1,...,log log n - 1 2k - log log n / k
      = log(n) ⋅ Σk=1,...,log log n - 1 2k ⋅ 2- log log n / k
      = log(n) ⋅ Σk=1,...,log log n - 1 2k / (k ⋅ log n)
      = Σk=1,...,log log n - 1 2k / k
```

In the line marked with (1) I reordered the sum.

So, at the end we "only" have to calculate `Σk=1,...,t 2k / k` for `t = log log n - 1`. At this point Maple solves this to

```
Σk=1,...,t 2k / k = -I⋅π - 2t⋅LerchPhi(2, 1, t)  +2t/t
```

where `I` is the imaginary unit and `LerchPhi` is the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Definition). Since the result for the sum above is a real number for all relevant cases, we can just ignore all imaginary parts. The Lerch transcendent `LerchPhi(2,1,t)` seems to be in `O(-1/t)`, but I'm not 100% sure about it. Maybe someone will prove this.

Finally this results in

```
T₂(n) = -2t⋅O(-1/t) + 2t/t = O(2t/t) = O(log n / log log n)
```

All together we have `T(n) ∈ Ω(log n / log log n)` and `T(n) ∈ O(log n/ log log n)`,
so `T(n) ∈ Θ(log n/ log log n)` holds. This result is also supported by your example data.

I hope this is understandable and it helps a little.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Besides, I've just learned a so-called "master theorem"  to simplify the last part of your proof, which you may see in my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The guts of the problem of verifying the conjectured estimate is to get a good estimate of plugging the value

```
n / log(n)
```

into the function

```
n --> log(n) / log(log(n))
```

**Theorem**:

```
log( n/log(n) ) / log(log( n/log(n) )) = log(n)/log(log(n)) - 1 + o(1)
```

(in case of font readibility issues, that's little-oh, not big-oh)

**Proof:**

To save on notation, write

```
A = n
B = log(n)
C = log(log(n))
```

The work is based on the first-order approximation to the (natural) logarithm: when `0 < y < x`,

```
log(x) - y/x < log(x - y) < log(x)
```

The value we're trying to estimate is

```
log(A/B) / log(log(A/B)) = (B - C) / log(B - C)
```

Applying the bounds for the logarithm of a difference gives

```
(B-C) / log(B) < (B-C) / log(B-C) < (B-C) / (log(B) - C/B)
```

that is,

```
(B-C) / C < (B-C) / log(B-C) < (B-C)B / (C (B-1))
```

Both the recursion we're trying to satisfy and the lower bound suggest we should estimate this with `B/C - 1`. Pulling that off of both sides gives

```
B/C - 1 < (B-C) / log(B-C) < B/C - 1 + (B-C)/(C(B-1))
```

and thus we conclude

```
(B-C) / log(B-C) = B/C - 1 + o(1)
```

---

If you take away one idea from this analysis to use on your own, let it be the point of using differential approximations (or even higher order Taylor series) to replace complicated functions with simpler ones. e.g. once you have the idea to use

```
log(x-y) = log(x) + Θ(y/x) when y = o(x)
```

then all of the algebraic calculations you need for your problem simply follow directly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer of @AbcAeffchen

I'm the owner of the question, using the knowledge of "the master method" I learned yesterday, the "a little bit harder" part of proof can be done as follows simply.
[image: The master method]

I will start here:

```
T(n) = T(sqrt(n)) + O(log(sqrt(n)) / log(log(sqrt(n))))
⇔ T(n)=T(sqrt(n)) + O(log n  / log log n)
```

Let

> n=2<sup>k</sup> , S(k)=T(2<sup>k</sup>)

then we have

> T(2<sup>k</sup>) =T(2<sup>k/2</sup>) + O(log 2<sup>k</sup>  / log log
>   2<sup>k</sup>) ⇔ S(k) =S(k/2) + O( k/log k)

with the master method

> S(k)=a*S(k/b)+f(k), where `a=1, b=2`, f(k)=k/log k
>   = Ω(k<sup>log<sub>2</sub>1 +ε</sup>) = Ω(k<sup>ε</sup>)，

as long as `ε∈(0,1)`

so we can apply case 3. Then

> S(k) = O(k/log k)
>
> T(n) = S(k) = O(k/log k) = O(log n/ log log n)

Comment: This is much easier than mine :D